# MS graph API in Azure Data Factory, return only 20 items

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pull the O365 user data on my company in Azure Data Factory by calling MS Graph API. According to the documentation of Graph API, plus various online sources, the pagination of this API should be set so that it automatically go to the next page indicated by @odata.nextLink.
Except, when I run this copy activity, I am only able to get 60+ users while it should be 2000+.
Below are screen shots of the config of this copy activity.

I am pulling hair at this point...

[image: api pagination config]
[image: api url]

I have tried changing the content of the pagination after Body to the following:

- {@odata.nextLink}
- @odata.nextLink
- $['@odata.nextLink']

Thanks!

Edit:
I forgot to mention that the authentication type is set to System Assigned Managed Identity.

Another piece of information, the users extracted are evenly distributed according to their user names alphabetical. Meaning the result looks something like this:

**user_id**
alex
antoine
bxxx
bxxx
cxxx
.
.
.
.
yxxx
yxxx

This suggests that the api is indeed calling through all the record, but pulling only one (or a few) line(s) per page. Has anyone else seen this?

Update:
So I did some digging, turns out the problem comes from mapping. When I imported schema in mapping, there was a '[0]' (see picture below) in the source, which caused the activity to grab only the first row.
[mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTP7q.png)

Comment: cam yo provide sample url and response?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the Body value to nextLink only?

or

Value type to "None" and value to $['@odata.nextLink']

[image]

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, and one user was extracted...

Comment: Another thing that you can try is changing the Value to "None" and use $['@odata.nextLink']

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. It is giving the same result as in my original method...

Answer (score 0):

I tried with ['@odata.nextLink'] but the output return only odata.nextLink and odata.count

Comment: Did you retire the [0] ?